# make multiple strings as one string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, string-concatenation

how should i make all the numbers as one string and not multiple individual strings?

I have tried like this:

```
   if len(key_val[1]) > 3:
        dictio[key_val[0]] = list(str(key_val[1]))
```

I get this output:

```
    {'parameter': ['1', '1', '0', '7', '4', '1', '3', '3', '6', '2']}
```

but the strings should only be one string.

Comment: What do you think `list()` does?

Comment: What is `key_val[1]`?

Comment: Makes the key_val a list.

Comment: @bronsje And why would you want that if you want a string?

Comment: key_val[1] = 1107413362

Comment: i want a list with a string inside

Comment: @bronsje Then just use str(key_val[1]) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to this:

```
if len(key_val[1]) > 3:
    dictio[key_val[0]] = [str(key_val[1])]
```

Then your result will be:

```
{'parameter': ['1107413362']}
```

The reason is that `list()` iterates over the string, which yields each character, and that turns each character into its own item in the list. If you want to just have a list, and the string be a value in that list, you can do what I showed above using `[]` to create a list with a list literal, of if you pre-configure that key to already be a list, you can then just append the string to it. But I think what I showed above is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If the expected output is `{'parameter': ['1107413362']}` then use a list literal:

```
dictio[key_val[0]] = [str(key_val[1])]
```

The `list()` constructor only takes an iterable as an argument; it'll take all the *elements* from the argument to make a new list object, and a string is a sequence of separate characters. Don't use it if you want to create a list *containing* an object.